# What's the co-op experience of Lara Croft and the Guardian of Light really like?

Tags: lara-croft-the-guardian-of-light

I've read good things in reviews about the co-op experience in Lara Croft and the Guardian of Light - specifically, that the puzzles change to accommodate both characters with their unique abilities.

Does playing co-op really change *all* the puzzles so that they *require* cooperation, or only a few select ones? Does this include the skull tombs? Does anything in the game change except for puzzles - for example is the combat more difficult, now that there are two gun-wielding players?

Finally, what happens when one of the characters dies?

Comment: Here's a little [gameplay comparison video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHRGlK7J_UA&t=2m52s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been playing for the past week with one of my friends (over PSN, not locally) and it's tons of fun! I was sceptical when I first saw the game but it's a blast to play, and it's actually a lot more fun playing co-op than single player because you get to (and often have to) help each other out, both in combat and for the puzzles.

Most of the puzzles change to need co-operation, usually something as simple as Lara using the rope to make a bridge for Totec, or Totec throwing spears to create stepping stones and such. The skull tomb puzzles tend to be a little bit more difficult as well, as it needs two players working together. Nothing too hard, though.

Not sure if the combat scales up to be honest, but it's a little more lenient with the deaths as the other player has a few seconds to revive you. If they don't, you revive with a bit more of a delay, but it's not more than 5 or 10 seconds.

As I said, I've been playing with a friend, not strangers, but I'm sure that it would be fun either way! :)